# Vieta's Formula failed?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> Find the possible values of $p$ for which $p$ and $q$ are the solutions of the equation
> $$x^2+px+q=0, \ \ \{x,p,q\}\in\ \mathbb{R}.$$

Plugging $p$ and $q$ into the given equation
$\begin{cases}
2p^2+q=0 \\[2ex]
q^2+pq+q=0
\end{cases}$

gives $p=\{0,1,-\dfrac{1}{2}\},$ which is the answer given by my book.

On the other hand, using [Vieta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)  for the sum and product of roots
$\begin{cases}
p+q=-p \\[2ex]
pq=q
\end{cases}$

gives $p=\{0,1\}.$ I am highly confused as to why Vieta's formula fails.

Comment: @ Will Jagy: I didn't understand , can u add context ?

Comment: how a degree 2 ploy can have 3 answers ? do you check the feasibility ?

Comment: if p is a rout how a degree two linear equation can have 3 roots ? i am confused.

Comment: @cardinal: It is not showing $3$ roots, its showing $3$ possibilities of a single root

Comment: so, i just said that check the feasibility to reject two of them !

Comment: So your book claims $p=-\frac12$. Then $q = 1$ because
$$p+q = -p$$
But according to the product of roots $$pq = q$$ $q=0$. Which is a contradiction.

Comment: @Cardinal: The system of equations does in fact have $3$ possible combinations of $(p,q)$. The problem is that why OP cannot arrive into those by vieta's formulas.

Comment: because, one of these options is not feasible ! the formula is based on feasibility !!!

Answer (score 4):

In short, the difference is because the Vieta formulae assume that $p$ and $q$ are different roots of the equation (in the sense of corresponding to different factors — not necessarily in the sense of being numerically unequal), while your second system only assumes that $p$ and $q$ both solve the equation.

To be more explicit, let's solve your second system to see what's going on. Subtracting the two equations from each other gives
$$
q^2+pq-2p^2=0\\
(q-p)(q+2p)=0
$$

So either $q=p$ or $q=-2p$.

If $q=-2p$, we get $2p^2-2p=0$, so either $p=q=0$ or $p=1$, $q=-2$. Note that both of these are solutions to the Vieta system as well.

If $q=p$, we get $2p^2+p=0$, so either $p=q=0$ (again) or $p=q=-1/2$. This last solution *does not* satisfy the Vieta formulae. Why not? Because it means the original equation was
$$
x^2-\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{2}=0
$$
which has solutions $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $x=1$. So in this case both $p$ and $q$ are roots of $x^2+px+q$, but they aren't "the" roots of $x^2+px+q$ (since they're both the same root).

Comment: Nice answer. And to expand on this, from the process that gives the three answer,
$$\begin{cases}
2p^2+q = 0\\
q^2 + pq + q = 0
\end{cases}$$
$$
\begin{align*}
q &= -2p^2\\
4p^4-2p^3-2p^2 &= 0\\
p^2(2p+1)(p-1) &= 0
\end{align*}
$$
neither of the constraints $p+q = -p$ nor $pq = q$ are considered.

Comment: So the book's answer is wrong, which should be underlined: the question says that “$p$ and $q$ are the roots”, not that “$p$ and $q$ are roots”. There's a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

> > Find the possible values of $p$ for which $p$ and $q$ are ***the*** solutions of the equation
> > $$x^2+px+q=0, \ \ \{x,p,q\}\in\ \mathbb{R}.$$
>
> Plugging $p$ and $q$ into the given equation  $\begin{cases} 2p^2+q=0
>  \\[2ex] q^2+pq+q=0 \end{cases}$
>
> gives $p=\left\{0,1,-\dfrac{1}{2}\right\},$ which is the answer given by my book.

Your book's answer is wrong. It is a mistake to translate

1. $p$ and $q$ are (all) ***the*** solutions of $x^2+px+q=0$

as the weaker statement

2. $p$ and $q$ satisfy $x^2+px+q=0\quad$ (i.e., $p$ and $q$ are solutions of $x^2+px+q=0$).

Since statement 1 implies statement 2 and we don't initially know whether is converse is true, the key is to note that the latter may introduce extraneous possibilities (while capturing at least all the required possibilities); so, we need to check whether any possibility needs to be eliminated from the latter. Here, since $p=-\dfrac12$ gives rise to $p=-\frac12=q$ yet the equation $x^2-\frac12x-\frac12=0$ has solutions $-\frac12$ and $1$ instead of just $-\frac12,$ we deduce that the value $p=-\dfrac12$ fails to satisfy statement 1 (the given statement).

> On the other hand, using [Vieta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)  for the sum and product of roots
> $\begin{cases}
> p+q=-p \\[2ex]
> pq=q
> \end{cases}$
>
> gives $p=\left\{0,1\right\}.$ I am highly confused as to why Vieta's formula fails.

Vieta's formula has not failed, because $p$ really can equal only either $0$ or $1.$

P.S. And that "$\{x,p,q\}\subset\ \mathbb{R}$" restriction turns out to have been redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks 'For which values of $p,q$ do we have

$$x^2+px+q=(x-p)(x-q)$$

?'

A simple expansion of the RHS gives

$$x^2+px+q=x^2-(p+q)x+pq$$

Hence the application of Vieta's formulas, and gives $(p,q)=(0,0),(1,-2)$.

The book's solution finds answers to 'For which values of $p,q$ do we have

$$x^2+px+q=0$$
$$(x-p)(x-q)=0$$

?'

which is a different question, and gives the extra answer of $(p,q)=(-\frac12,-\frac12)$.

Comment: How can imposing an extra equation (the =0) allow an extra solution to appear? Your restatements of the question are a little off since you don't say what x means. In your first restatement you imply the equation should hold for all x, i.e. that the two sides are equal as polynomials (and while that is equivalent to the original question, that is confusing). In your second restatement, it is unclear what to do with x when we "have" the equations.