# Find $p$ and $q$ in $x^2-px+q=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> If $p$ and $q$ are the roots of the equation $x^2-px+q=0,\ \{x,p,q\}\in\mathbb{R} $, then find $p$ and $q$.

I tried sum and product of the roots formula and got ,

$$p+q=p \\pq=q$$

I found $q=0$ ,but I am confused on how to find $p$ since I cannot divide $q$ when $q=0$.

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.

Comment: Check this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363749/vietas-formula-failed

Comment: You cannot divide by $0$, and it's not needed. If $q=0$, you have $p\cdot 0 = 0$, and it's always true. So, $q=0$ is solution; while we cannot determine $p$, any $p$ is solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go back to the initial equation:  $x^2 - px + 0 = x(x-p) = 0$ has roots $p$ and $0$ for all $p \in \mathbb{R}$.  So it works for any $p$.